# Can / Should I use SWT or SAML tokens for MVC 4 WebAPI project?

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have setup my ACS in Azure.
I have created a MVC 4 WebAPI Project.
I have added "Identity and Access" in visual studio 2012.

This are running. but when i lauch the application i get the following:
ID4014: A SecurityTokenHandler is not registered to read security token ('BinarySecurityToken', 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd').

The problem is that i told ACS to use SWT instead of SAML 2.0. From what I have seen in guides about securing a restfull wep api, swt was the way to go.

If i change to SAML 2.0 it all works in the web interface. But how will this work out when i write a client for Windows Store (Metro) or other clients to get data from the WebAPI part of the project?

Any advice to continue. Should I use SWT, and how do it make it work. Should I use SAML 2.0 and what should i then handle the authenticaitno later in a Windows Store Client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nuget packaged wif.swt that enabled swt tokens.

```xml
 <microsoft.identityModel>
    <service saveBootstrapTokens="true">
      <audienceUris>
        <!--<add value="http://traffictheory.cloudapp.net/" />-->
        <add value="http://77.55.160.102:48451/" />
      </audienceUris>
      <issuerNameRegistry type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Swt.SwtIssuerNameRegistry, Wif.Swt">
        <trustedIssuers>
          <add thumbprint="033F53598E4ED92E51C07238E36BBFF4E67ABAD2" name="https://traffictheory.accesscontrol.windows.net/" />
        </trustedIssuers>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
      <claimsAuthenticationManager type="S_Innovations.TrafficTheory.Web.Security.TrafficTheoryClaimsAuthenticationManager, S-Innovations.TrafficTheory.Web.Security" />
      <federatedAuthentication>
        <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
        <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://traffictheory.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/wsfederation" realm="http://77.55.160.102:48451/" reply="http://77.55.160.102:48451/" requireHttps="false" />
      </federatedAuthentication>
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
      <securityTokenHandlers>
            <add type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Swt.SwtSecurityTokenHandler, Wif.Swt" />
        </securityTokenHandlers>
        <issuerTokenResolver type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Swt.SwtIssuerTokenResolver, Wif.Swt" />
      <!--<serviceCertificate>
        <certificateReference findValue="‎417DE8DCA4326B845C189BDE0990673433435524" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
      </serviceCertificate>-->    
    </service>
  </microsoft.identityModel>
```

Comment: One problem though: I dont know how the token should look like when passing it from my client to the site.

Comment: When I used the "Identity and Access" it added two sections "system.identityModel" and "system.identityModel.services". The "wif.swt" nugget package adds a section "microsoft.identityModel". Do I need the system.identityModel sections?

Comment: microsoft.identityModel was from before it got integrated into the stack. if Identity and Access adds system.identityModel you are working with the newer version and should properly not use the old wif package.